# How to assign the string in 2 vector in R

Tags: r

I work with R et Rstudio and I have a problem.

First, i have 2 vectors:

```
cap-color               
cap-color               
odor                    
odor                    
odor                    
odor                    
gill-spacing            
gill-size               
gill-color              
stalk-surface-above-ring
stalk-color-above-ring  
spore-print-color       
spore-print-color       
population              
population
```

AND:

```
buff     
pink     
creosote 
foul     
musty    
pungent  
close    
narrow   
buff     
silky    
cinnamon 

chocolate

green    

scattered

several
```

Now, i want an output as:

```
cap-color ∈ {buff, pink}
odor ∈ {creosote, foul, musty, pungent}
gill-spacing = {close}
gill-size = {narrow}
gill-color = {buff}
stalk-surface-above-ring = {silky}
stalk-color-above-ring = {cinnamon}
spore-print-color ∈ {chocolate, green}
population ∈ {scattered, several}
```

Comment: `cap-color <- c("buff" , "pink")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make that a data.table then paste the elements of vector 2 grouping by vector 1

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table("Name"=vector1,"Var"=vector2)
res <- dt[,paste(Var,collapse=","),by=Name]

res
                   Name                          V1
1:                cap-color                   buff,pink
2:                     odor creosote,foul,musty,pungent
3:             gill-spacing                       close
4:                gill-size                      narrow
5:               gill-color                        buff
6: stalk-surface-above-ring                       silky
7:   stalk-color-above-ring                    cinnamon
8:        spore-print-color             chocolate,green
9:               population           scattered,several
```

Next time give the desired output in actual R output format, list or data frame for example

Comment: Is there an other, please? I don't want use a data.table.